# How to bake normal map identical to one from cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

In my project I have normal map defined by nodes in Cycles which I use to render my scene -- here are relevant nodes:

[image]

Image texture is a seamless square normal map image.

Later I also decided to bake normal map with Blender Internal. I would like the baked normal map to be identical to one generated in Cycles. What would be settings in BI for that?

Answer (score 3):

To align normal maps to match GLSL I use Photoshop.  By using the *Channel Mixer* tool you can swap axis.  Swapping *Green* and *Blue* is the same as swapping the *Y-Axis* and the *Z-Axis*.  Then you can also use the *Curves* tool to change the direction of an axis which is the same as multiplying the value by -1.0.

I've attached a picture that shows a PS *Action*.

For your situation specifically, I'm not sure which combination of operations that you require but you can grab yourself a copy of *xNormal* to help with this.  In the *Normal Baking* window there is the option to perform all this swapping with a simple GUI.  You can try what you think will work and then bake the normal map to see if it looks the same as what you need.  Once you know this, you can use either GIMP or PS to do the conversion after you've baked a map in Blender.

[image]